# Android and IOS app not working after changing server IP address

Tags: android, ios, swift, xcode, android-studio

I have a web application developed in laravel with Android App (Java) and IOS App (Swift). I changed my webserver but now mobile apps are not working.

Domain is same but only the IP was changed.

Am i facing the issue because of changing IP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ip change can take some time to propagate. Have you tried using

```
ping yourdomain.tld
```

From your terminal or an [internet service](https://network-tools.com/ping/)?
You can also use [InetAddress](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/InetAddress.html) to do it in your app code with `InetAddress.getByName("www.yourdomain.tld")` (but don't run it in the main thread).

Other than that I think that something is caching the old ip value and returning it.